# Jetpack compose BottomsheetScaffold BottomSheetValue.Expanded default value pops at the top of the screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want to use
When the user arrives on the page, the bottomsheet pops at the top of the screen before beeing dragged down to the bottom of the screen (where it is supposed to be)

Here is a code that reproduces the issue :

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun testBottomsheet(){
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Open),
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Expanded),
    )
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Hello from sheet")
            }
        }, sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
    ) {
            Button(onClick = {
            }) {
                Text(text = "Expand/Collapse Bottom Sheet")
            }
    }
}
```